# Graph embedding in space: always possible?

Tags: graph-theory

Because graph theory is mostly concerned with embeddings on surfaces, I was wondering what would happen if we would consider higher-dimensional objects.

My question is: can every graph always be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Maybe this is a very silly question with an easy answer, but I don't see any obvious way to prove it.

Anyway, I'm happy to receive any answers, references or suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Every (finite) graph can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Imagine that we place $n$ vertices in $(0,0,1),\dots,(0,0,n)$, and $m$ edges can be well embedded in those planes $x=jy$ ($j=1,\dots,m$). Briefly to explain, it is like putting vertices in the spine of a book, and placing the edges in the pages.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the graph to have straight edges. Consider the real spacecurve parametrized by $(t,t^2,t^3)$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Now if 4 points on this spacecurve are coplanar, then two of these coincide, this is obvious from $$\det\begin{pmatrix}a-b & a-c & a-d\\
a^2-b^2 & a^2-c^2 & a^2-d^2\\
a^3-b^3 & a^3-c^3 & a^3-d^3 
\end{pmatrix}=(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(d-b)(d-c)(c-b).$$ Hence we can embed any graph of cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the converse is of course also true.

Comment: Rudy Jones approves this!

Comment: pra pra pra rra